# How to deal with character columns for a random forest with Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataframe with a column 'title', 'content'. It's about some newspaper article. I want to do a random forest on that in order to predict a variable : negatif, positif or neutral.

So my features variables will be title and content and my exploratory variable will be for instance "sentiment" (negatif, positif or neutral).
The problem is that I have only character column. I can't do some encoding as One Hot encoding because all the raw are different, so it will have many different encodings as there are lines.

I don't know how to proceed... Can I specify by myself the exploratory variable by hand for the training set ? If you have some indications in order I continue my project, thanks a lot !!!

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["title", "content"], data=[["The Rise and Fall of Heidelberg Street","McDougall-Hunt a small neighborhood of single-..."]])
df.head()

title                                           content

The Rise and Fall of Heidelberg Street          McDougall-Hunt a small neighborhood of single-...
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data (e.g. `df.head()`)? I don't understand what a "character column" is.

Comment: Sure I edit my post, thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a baseline, I would advise you to use TF-IDF `TfidfTransformer` to have a vectorized representation of your text.

TF-IDF is basically a statistical measure that evaluates how relevant a word is to a document in a collection of documents.

You can simply concatenate both title and content and then pass it through this pipeline:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

df['text'] = df['title']+' '+df['content']
X=df['text']
y=df['sentiment']
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])
pipeline.fit(X, y)
```

I suggest you read those feature extractions documentation as they will help you to understand how they work.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot ! So need I to classify manualy my text for the data train ?

Comment: If you do not have the sentiment value; yes. Otherwise, you could use the package `vaderSentiment` to extract the sentiment of your text. It's a package that performs a lexicon and rule-based sentiment analysis.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert them to dummy variables using

```
import pandas as pd
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! The problem is that my column "content" are different for each raw, so I think it will be a problem for the prediction...

Comment: In this case, the column "content" won't be able to provide any additional information to the model and so can be dropped.

Comment: Alternatively, if the field is some kind of free-text field and you care about the information contained within it, the TFIDIF approach mentioned about would be useful.

Comment: I found the solution for my problem, thanks a lot ! :)